# Forward proxy with squid or anything else

Tags: proxy, http, haproxy, squid, socks

i have a server with few thousands of IPv6s i want to create a forward proxy server with it which do the following:

- port forwarding (X.X.X.25:PORT -> IPV6 outgoing traffic)
- basic username/password authentication
- support socks5 (not required but it will be awesome)

there are many sites doing this so i'm sure it's possible, googled for few days with not much luck.

**what i've found so far:**

i have tried squid with the following configuration and it's work fine, the only problem is that i can only bind to 128 'http_port's. as you can see it's not enough for my purpose, here's my configuration:

```
auth_param basic program /usr/lib64/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/users
auth_param basic children 100
auth_param basic realm Enter your User/PASS
auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours
auth_param basic casesensitive off
acl ncsa_users proxy_auth REQUIRED

http_port X.X.X.25:3000
http_port X.X.X.25:3001
http_port X.X.X.25:3002
http_port X.X.X.25:3003
...
http_port X.X.X.25:4000

acl ip0 myportname X.X.X.25:3000
acl ip1 myportname X.X.X.25:3001
acl ip2 myportname X.X.X.25:3002
...
acl ip999 myportname X.X.X.25:4000

tcp_outgoing_address X:X:X:X:8000:0000:ff12:ac5b ip0
tcp_outgoing_address X:X:X:X:8000:0000:ff13:ac6b ip1
tcp_outgoing_address X:X:X:X:8000:0000:ff14:ac7b ip2
...
tcp_outgoing_address X:X:X:X:8000:0000:ff15:f38b ip1000
```

the first 128 ports works fine but the rest won't i've found a solution on stackoverflow to increase this number but it's said to infect performance (even by increasing to 256 which i want to increase to few thousands)

i've also tried to make a work around with nginx and haproxy again with no luck. it seems they forward the port again to an external proxy server what i want is to create that external proxy server.

**please guide me**

i think squid isn't the right tool for doing what i'm doing, is there any other software or solution which i use to to this?

Comment: Perhaps run multiple parallel squids, each with thei own range of 128 ports?

Comment: @wurtel thanks for your comment, i thought about that as well but it will be very very hard to manage, a client might order 2 thousands of ips, it will be hard to calculate and manage multiple instances with 128 ports